# Profiling function time as a function of two parameters

Tags: r, profiling

Let's say I have a function that takes two inputs:

```
myfun = function(i,j){
  fac = factorial(i)
  c0 = crossprod(matrix(rnorm(j*j),nrow=j), matrix(rnorm(j*j),nrow=j))
  return(fac + c0)
}
```

And I'd like to understand how the execution time varies as a function of `i` and `j`.

Is there a way to profile this in R?

I want something to get something like a 2D matrix of execution times, with `i` and `j` on the x and y axis respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Given the function you have described you should be able to profile each argument separately and then add the time up, should you choose to, because the arguments are independent of each other. However, to answer your question, this is what I came up with:

```
# wrap function in timer
myfun_time <- function(i,j, type = "user.self"){

  system.time(myfun(i,j))[type]

} 

# choose points to evaluate at
i_vals <- c(0,10,50,100,120)
j_vals <- c(0,10,50,100,150)

# create evaluation matrix (all combinations of points)
eval_mat <- expand.grid(i = i_vals, j = j_vals)

# create matrix to help with location of points when moving from vector to matrix
loc_mat <- as.matrix(expand.grid(i = 1:length(i_vals), j = 1:length(j_vals)))

# run test
results_vec <- mapply(myfun_time, i = eval_mat$i, j = eval_mat$j)

# empty matrix to store results
results_mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = sqrt(nrow(eval_mat)), ncol = sqrt(nrow(eval_mat)), 
              dimnames = list(i_vals,j_vals))

# move results vector to matrix
results_mat[loc_mat] <- results_vec

# you can also repeat this and average the results...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `proc.time` command. This should work:

```
# Creates a matrix with i_max, j_max dimentions
times <- matrix(nrow = i_max, ncol = j_max)

for (i in 1:i_max) {
    for (j in 1:j_max) {
        # Start the clock
        ptm <- proc.time()

        # Execution
        exec <- myfun(i, j)

        # Final time
        time <- proc.time() - ptm

        # Adding it to the time matrix
        times[i, i] <- time[,1]
    }
}

# Show the times matrix
times
```

This will create the matrix you mentioned. I chose `time[,1]` because the `proc.time()` returns 3 values, and the one concerning the execution of the function is the first one, you can read about it here: [R FAQ How can I time my code?](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/timing_code.htm)

Hope this helped!